# how to exclude few files/folder from using preserved cypress cookies

Tags: cookies, cypress, session-cookies, cypress-configuration

I am trying to preserve cookies in index.js file :

```js
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: ['session_id', 'remember_token'],
})
```

But I want to exclude few files such as login/authentication files from using the preserved cookies because I want to test real login here.

I see that cypress provides something like:

```js
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: (cookie) => {
    // implement your own logic here
    // if the function returns truthy
    // then the cookie will not be cleared
    // before each test runs
  },
})
```

But I am not sure how to exclude a folder/files inside this. If someone has an idea kindly help.
Or if there is any other better option to exclude files from using preserved cookies do let me know

Comment: You can try inverting the logic - use `Cookies.preserveOnce()` in `beforeEach()` for the specs that should send cookies.

Comment: Also, consider this recipe [stubbing / spying win navigator cookieEnabled](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/stubbing-spying__navigator/cypress/integration/spec.js)

Comment: @Fody thanks for the suggestion. I already made this work using cookies.preserveOnce() in beforeEach. Since, most of my spec files needs cookies so only want to exclude some files. Also I don't want to use some stubbing here, because I am testing logging/ authentication section where I want to hit my server just like an end user does. :)

Comment: The point of using stubbing is to only apply it for the tests that should not see the cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to exclude Cookies based on what spec file is running. Instead, you could clear them in the specs that you do not want values, and create a helper to check they are set in the specs.

```js
// support/index.js
...
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: ['session_id', 'remember_token'],
})
Cypress.Commands.add('setDefaultCookies', () => {
  const defaults = { 'session_id': 'foo', 'rememberToken': 'bar' }
  cy.getCookies().then((cookies) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(defaults) {
      // use `find` to check if we have the specified cookie
      const found = cookies.find(x => x.name === key);
      if (!found) {
        cy.setCookie(key, value);
      }
    };
  });  
});
...

// auth.spec.js (doesn't want cookies)
...
before(() => {
  cy.clearCookies();
});
...

// foo.spec.js (wants cookies)
...
before(() => {
  cy.setDefaultCookies();
});
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to clear in the respective spec where I don't want cookies, it dint work. Because I have preserved cookies in `Cypress.Cookies.defaults({`

Comment: @user3378508 you should use `cy.setDefaultCookies()` ***instead*** of `Cypress.Cookies.defaults`. Obviously if you want to control cookies per spec, you cannot use a global setting.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Cypress.Cookies.defaults` preserve function you can return true or false depending on the cookie properties and the current spec properties.

```js
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: (cookie) => {

    const isLogin  = Cypress.spec.name.contains('login') ||  // e.g login.spec.js
      Cypress.spec.relative.contains('login');               // e.g /login-tests/...

    if (cookie.name === 'token' && isLogin {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  },
})
```